# Does Enlist trigger itself?

Tags: scythe

In Scythe, one of the actions that you can take is to enlist a recruit. When you do, you get on ongoing benefit for the rest of the game. Does the "rest of the game" include the action that you just took?

If it does, then enlisting the recruit from the Enlist section of your player board will always give you +1 popularity right away, because that is the benefit associated with the Enlist action that you just took.

From page 20 of the [Scythe rules](https://m.box.com/shared_item/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Frj3jrw0rab2uiz02up89kbant5g8ew1p/view/49368403634):

> "For the rest of the game, whenever you or the player to your
>   immediate left or right (these players are shown in the icon in the
>   red circle) take the bottom-row action in the section of the Player
>   Mat from which the recruit was taken, you may gain the specified
>   bonus."

My group guessed "no", but we felt that the wording is ambiguous. Can anyone come up with a FAQ or designer comment that will clarify the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you would not gain the benefit the same turn you enlist it.

Jamey Stegmaier, Scythe designer, answered this question in a [thread on boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/24772003#24772003)

> The costs and benefits for the player mat are those that are visible before you take the action, so you would not gain the ongoing recruit bonus from the enlist action until your next enlistment.